# c++ error: no matching function for all to

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors

I'm trying to implement a function which return a class object using its constructor.
that class object as only constructor with parameters and there isnt any default constructor (cuz i dont need it).
when I try to return that class object - that error comes up..

**Base.cpp**

Derived Base::operator+ (){
    return Derived(*this); // no matching function for call to ‘Derived::Derived(Derived)’
}

**Base.h**

virtual Derived operator+ ();

**Derived.h**
//Constructors:

Derived(Base &b);

Derived(Derived &d);

*1. what can I do in order to fix that error?*

*2. whats the diffrence between declaration (const Derived &) and (Derived &)?*

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of operator+() here?

Comment: How does Base can see your Derived class? I assume Derived derives from Base.

Answer (score 1):

`Derived&` will not bind to a temporary object. Your `operator+` returns a temporary.

Solution: add `const` because `const&` will bind to temporaries.

Comment: add const to both constructors?

Comment: if I add const to the constructor, I need to change the member of the constructor to const. the problem is that if so, I cannot change that object with assignment operator which I need to implement

Comment: @michal_h: No, you add const to the _source_ object of the copy contructor. That does not affect the members, because in a copy constructor and in the assignment operator you only write to the members of the _destination_ object.

Comment: when i write:

Derived::Derived(const Derived & other){
 m_d=other;
}

its says: uninitialized reference member 'Derived'